# How is water vapor removed in a vacuum oven?

Tags: thermodynamics

I’ve been doing research on vacuum chambers/ovens and I have not been able to find any information beyond their basic function.

I would like to know what happens to the water vapor once it is separated from solids under vacuum. Does the vapor stay in the chamber? Or is there some kind of collection system attached as well? If so, how does that system operate?

In my mind, I picture the vapor dispersed in the vacuum, then once pressure is reintroduced it would become liquid again in same chamber as the test material so I’m clearly missing a crucial point in the process here.

Comment: There is a pump?

Comment: The water will have a vapor pressure greater than than the vacuum which the vacuum pump can create. So the water gets pulled into/through the vacuum pump.

Answer (score 3):

Water vapour is a gas. It gets pumped out with the other gases.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a pump, the evaporated water vapour will indeed get pumped out together with any air in the chamber. However, if the pressure inside the vacuum chamber is not zero (which is the real case), then an amount of it will remain in proportion to the pressure inside the chamber. A lower chamber pressure means less water vapour and air will remain. The pump does not prefer the water vapour in relation to the remaining air.